# Строковый буфер Си

Tags: c, строки, потоки-данных

Какой есть на Си строковый буфер вроде `stringstream` на C++, и как им пользоваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандарте POSIX 2008 есть весьма удобная функция: *[open_memstream](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html)()*. Вы можете сделать так:

```
// здесь в итоге появятся записанные значения и размер текста:
char* buffer = NULL;
size_t bufferSize = 0;

// создаём поток с указателями для выходных значений:
FILE* myStream = open_memstream(&buffer, &bufferSize);

// можно записывать в поток как в обычный вывод:
fprintf(myStream, "You can output anything to myStream, just as you can with stdout.\n");

// можно добавить что-либо ещё с неизвестным размером в других функциях:
myComplexPrintFunction(myStream);

// закрытие потока перенесёт данные и размер в buffer и bufferSize:
fclose(myStream);

// теперь можно делать что угодно с полученной строкой:
printf("I can do anything with the resulting string now. It is: \"%s\"\n", buffer);

// ну и не забывайте чистить память:
free(buffer);
```

<sub>Перевод ответа: [String Stream in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121640/5308802).</sub>