# Перехват stdout/stderr в C

Tags: c

Вводные данные: есть некая библиотека, которая при ошибках плюётся в stderr (stdout, не принципиально). Хочется сохранять это дело в свои переменные, а не портить консоль. Тем более что её может и не быть вовсе. Да и вообще, время и место вывода сообщения об ошибке хочется определять самостоятельно.

Самое простое решение - переоткрытие стандартных потоков и `setvbuf`. Тем более что авторами библиотеки предусмотрено их дублирование изначально. После чего всё становится как бы просто (`lib` - условная структура, содержащая данные для работы этой библиотеки):

```
setvbuf( lib.StdOut, lib.OutBuf, _IOFBF, LIB_OUTBUF_SIZE );

/* ... много кода ... */

if( someLibFunction() == FIGNYA ) {
    handleExternalLibError( lib.OutBuf ); /* здесь сообщение об ошибке */
}
```

Вопрос в значении этого самого `LIB_OUTBUF_SIZE`. Экспериментальным путём (и грипом по исходникам библиотеки) установлено, что там может быть имя файла. Одно, это важно, ну и какие-то тексты. Стало быть, выделяем `PATH_MAX+PATH_MAX`, чтобы влезло наверняка. А если там впихнут какую-нибудь `.po`-шность, да на немецком? Или какой там язык с самыми длинными ругательствами :)

В любом случае хочется какого-то универсального подхода. Идеи?

Comment: Не уверен, что лучшее решение, но как вариант - читать буфер в другом потоке во время выполнения `someLibFunction()`.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Ага, были такие идеи. Но вот многопоточности не хотелось бы. От слова "совсем" :) Не тот случай.

Comment: Да, и `setvbuf` только задаст буфер для потока, но предотвратит ли вывод в консоль? К тому же `You shouldn't try to access the values in the array directly while the stream is using it for buffering.` т.е. не рекомендуется лезть в буфер.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, там потоки переоткрываются, в данном случае хоть в `/dev/null`, или `NUL`, неважно. Вопрос только в размере. Достаточном для приёма сообщения в *общем случае*.

Comment: Вообще-то никто не гарантирует никакого конкретного способа использования буферизации. Да, буфер выделен, но что в нем в любой момент времени - никто вам гарантировать не может. Так что это способ, мягко говоря, ненадежный. Более того, не исключаю, что, обнаружив перенаправление в `nul`, достаточно интеллектуальная система будет просто полностью игнорировать буфер... :)

Comment: Вау, стопаньки. Мы говорим о C, FILE, и прочих гарантированых радостях. Так что тут без вариантов, простите. Если вы не в курсе - sorry.

Comment: Мне тоже в одном проекте нужен был вывод куда понадобится. [Сделал такой вывод в свой буфер](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523597/198251). Не переопределение стандартных, но может пойдёт?

Comment: @AivanF. Windows с POSIX дружит, мягко говоря, не очень :) А это одно из требований - делать так, чтобы собиралось студией, увы :(

Answer (score 1):

Основной момент здесь, неизвестный размер сообщения который приходит из библиотеки. Поэтому использовать статичный буффер не желатильно. Но если есть возможность перенаправить потоки. Почему не перенаправить в `pipe()`. А потом в нужном месте считать информацию из него.

Comment: Да, такой вариант рассматривался. Но это уж очень заморочно. Хотя, если сделать грамотную обёртку... Эх, ленивый народ - программисты :)

Answer (score 1):

> есть некая библиотека, которая при ошибках плюётся в stderr (stdout, не принципиально). Хочется сохранять это дело в свои переменные, а не портить консоль. Тем более что её может и не быть вовсе.

Можно перенаправить вывод в файл, используя [`freopen()` функцию](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("stdout is printed to console");
    if (freopen("redir.txt", "w", stdout) == NULL)
    {
       perror("freopen() failed");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts("stdout is redirected to a file"); // this is written to redir.txt
    fclose(stdout);
}
```

See [Rerouting stdin and stdout from C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/584868/4279). На POSIX `freopen()` может быть реализовано с помощью [`dup2()` (перенаправление на уровне файловых дескрипторов)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html), [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530437/23044).

Стоит упомянуть, что `stdout` НЕ гарантирован быть lvalue, поэтому не следует  писать: `stdout = ...`.

---

[`setvbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) не имеет никакого отношения к перехвату stdout/stderr в С. `setvbuf()` просто изменяет режим буферизации для заданного `FILE*` потока:

> The contents of the array after a successful call to setvbuf are indeterminate and any attempt to use it is undefined behavior.

Эта цитата из документации `setvbuf()` говорит, что использование `OutBuf` после успешного вызова `setvbuf()` является UB (например, стандарт разрешает запустить ракету на Марс, зашифровать жёсткий диск и не давать ключ до тех пор пока понятие "undefined behavior" и почему его следует избегать твёрдо в голове не отложится).

Последний аргумент у `setvbuf()` имеет тип `size_t`, поэтому `LIB_OUTBUF_SIZE` это не имя файла -- по смыслу это просто размер `OutBuf` буфера. `PATH_MAX` (["макс. длина пути"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/833291/4279)) также никаким боком к перехвату stdout/stderr в C не относится.

Если библиотека явно предоставляет `StdOut` переменную, то почитайте в её документации как эту переменную рекомендуют использовать, например:

```
StdOut = fmemopen(your_buffer, sizeof your_buffer, "w");
```

[fmemopen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) предполагает что ваша библиотека *никогда* не напишет больше чем `sizeof your_buffer` байт в `StdOut` поток.

Answer (score 0):

Как указывал в комментарии, можно создать свой буфер и записывать в него: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523597/198251). Здесь используется *open_memstream* из стандарта *POSIX 2008*. Для платформ без его поддержки существуют порты и аналогичные функции. Например, для [BSD и Mac OS, iOS](https://github.com/NimbusKit/memorymapping) и [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341073/5308802). Вот и всё, два зайца пойманы: задача решена, самому излишне копаться в теме не нужно `:)`

Comment: Я сам фанат подхода "виндовс маст дай", но если оно не собирается из нативных исходников в студии 2015 без "поддержки" - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, 100% надёжное решение заключается в использовании inotify, вот только не знаю - сгодится ли оно для видовоза... А именно:

1) Запускаем Вашу программу (например - test) с перенаправлением stdout/stderr в файл:

```
# test > err_msg.txt 2>&1
```

2) Внутри функции main инициализируем систему inotify:

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>
...
int main() {
...
int fd, wd;
fd = inotify_init();
```

3) Сообщаем OS, что желаем мониторить запись в файл  err_msg.txt

```
wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "err_msg.txt", IN_MODIFY );
```

4) А дальше есть два варианта:

4.1) Вы пытаетесь читать псевдофайл inottify после каждого вызова функции из библиотеки (неблокирующее чтение)
4.2) Вы организуете отдельную нитку для чтения этого файла.

5) По любому, если чтение

```
length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );  
if ( length < 0 ) {
    perror( "read" );
}
```

сработало, то это означает только одно - файл err_msg.txt был модифицирован и Вам надо на него посмотреть. Анализировать buffer, с целью узнать, какое именно событие произошло смысла нет - Вы запросили мониторинг только ОДНОГО события.

Ну а дальше - по обстоятельствам... :-)